# Programa no imprime los resultados

Tags: java, eclipse

Cuando ordeno los nodos de cualquier forma (marca, cilindraje o precio), no me imprime nada el programa. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Esta es la clase Motocicleta:

```
public class Motocicleta{
private String marca;
private double cilindraje;
private int precio;
Motocicleta siguiente;

  public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
  }

  public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
  }

  public double getCilindraje() {
    return cilindraje;
  }

  public void setCilindraje(double cilindraje) {
    this.cilindraje = cilindraje;
  }

  public int getPrecio() {
    return precio;
  }

  public void setPrecio(int precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
  }

}
```

Esta es la clase Principal:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Principal {
  Motocicleta cabeza;
  Motocicleta fin;
  Scanner lector;
  
  public Principal() {
    crearFlujo();
    menu();
  }

  public void crearFlujo() {
    lector = new Scanner(System.in);
  }

  public String leer() {
    return lector.nextLine();
  }

  public Motocicleta pedirDatos() {
    Motocicleta m = new Motocicleta();
    System.out.println("por favor, digite la marca");
    m.setMarca(leer());

    System.out.println("por favor, digite el cilindraje");
    m.setCilindraje(Double.parseDouble(leer()));

    System.out.println("por favor, digite el precio");
    m.setPrecio(Integer.parseInt(leer()));

    return m;
  }

  public void insertarMoto() {
    if (cabeza == null) {
      cabeza = pedirDatos();
      fin = cabeza;
    } else {
      Motocicleta aux = pedirDatos();
      fin.siguiente = aux;
      fin = aux;
    }
  }
  
  public void buscarMoto() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingresar moto a buscar: ");
        String bb = sc.nextLine();
        String bus = bb.toLowerCase();
        boolean encon = false;

        Motocicleta aux = cabeza;

        while (aux != null) {
          int t = bus.compareTo(aux.getMarca().toLowerCase());
          if (t == 0) {
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Marca: " + aux.getMarca());
            System.out.println("Cilindraje: " + aux.getCilindraje());
            System.out.println("Precio: " + aux.getPrecio());
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
            encon = true;
          }
          aux = aux.siguiente;

        }
        if (encon == false) {
          System.out.println("No se encontró la moto");
        }
        sc.close();
      }

public void imprimirMotos() {
        Motocicleta aux = cabeza;
            while (aux != null) {
              System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
              System.out.println("Marca: " + aux.getMarca());
              System.out.println("Cilindraje: " + aux.getCilindraje());
              System.out.println("Precio: " + aux.getPrecio());

              aux = aux.siguiente;
              System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");

            }
      }
  

  public void eliminarNodo() {
    Motocicleta nodo = cabeza;
    String marcaUsuario;
    System.out.println("Digite la marca de la moto que desea eliminar: ");
    marcaUsuario = leer();
    boolean flag = false;
    while (nodo != null) {
      if (nodo.getMarca().compareTo(marcaUsuario) == 0) {
        flag = true;
        System.out.println("Marca eliminada");
        if (nodo == cabeza) {
          cabeza = cabeza.siguiente;
        } else if (nodo == fin) {
          Motocicleta aux = cabeza;
          while (aux.siguiente != fin) {
            aux = aux.siguiente;
          }
          fin = null;
          fin = aux;
        } else {
          Motocicleta aux = cabeza;
          while (aux.siguiente != nodo) {
            aux = aux.siguiente;
          }
          aux.siguiente = nodo.siguiente;
          nodo = null;
        }
        break;
      }
      nodo = nodo.siguiente;
    }
    if (flag) {
      System.out.println("El registro de la moto ha sido eliminado");
    } else {
      System.out.println("No se encontró algun registro");
    }
  }  
  
  public void intercambiar(Motocicleta nodoi, Motocicleta nodoj) {
        Motocicleta temp = new Motocicleta();
        temp.setCilindraje(nodoi.getCilindraje());
        temp.setMarca(nodoi.getMarca());
        temp.setPrecio(nodoi.getPrecio());
        nodoi.setCilindraje(nodoj.getCilindraje());
        nodoi.setMarca(nodoj.getMarca());
        nodoi.setPrecio(nodoj.getPrecio());
        nodoj.setCilindraje(temp.getCilindraje());
        nodoj.setMarca(temp.getMarca());
        nodoj.setPrecio(temp.getPrecio());
      }
  
  public void ordenarMotosa() {

      if (cabeza != null) {
          System.out.println("Digite el comando del atributo por el cual desea ordenar");
          System.out.println("1) Marca");
          System.out.println("2) Cilindraje");
          System.out.println("3) Precio");
          int OpcionAtributo = Integer.parseInt(leer());

          Motocicleta nodoi = cabeza;
          if (cabeza.siguiente != null) {
            while (nodoi != null) {
              Motocicleta nodoj = nodoi.siguiente;
              while (nodoj != null) {
                switch (OpcionAtributo) {
                  case 1:
                    if (nodoi.getMarca().compareTo(nodoj.getMarca())> 0) {
                      intercambiar(nodoi, nodoj);

                    }
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    if (nodoi.getCilindraje() > nodoj.getCilindraje()) {
                      intercambiar(nodoi, nodoj);

                    }
                    break;
                  case 3:
                    if (nodoi.getPrecio() > nodoj.getPrecio()) {
                      intercambiar(nodoi, nodoj);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                nodoj = nodoi.siguiente;

              }
              nodoj = nodoi.siguiente;
            }
          } else {
            System.out.println(nodoi);
          }
        } else {
          System.out.println("No hay lista a ordenar");
        }

      }
    
  
  public void menu() {
    int opcion;
    do {
      System.out.println("          BIENVENDO A LA VENTA DE MOTOCICLETAS    ");
      System.out.println("                por favor digite una opcion              ");
      System.out.println("                   1) crear motocicleta                    ");
      System.out.println("                  2) buscar motocicleta                   ");
      System.out.println("                  3) listar motocicleta                   ");
      System.out.println("                 4) Eliminar motocicleta                 ");
      System.out.println("                 5) Ordenar motocicletas              ");
      System.out.println("                        6) Salir                 ");
      opcion = Integer.parseInt(leer());

      switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
          insertarMoto();
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("buscando moto");
          buscarMoto();
          break;
        case 3:
          System.out.println("listando motos");
          imprimirMotos();
          break;
        case 4:
          eliminarNodo();
          break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("ordenando motos");
            ordenarMotosa();
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("gracias por participar");
            break;  
        default:
          System.out.println("por favor digite una opción valida entre 1-6");
          break;
      }

    } while (opcion!=6);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Principal p=new Principal();
  }
```

Mi problema es que cuando le doy la opción 5, me muestra un menú de opciones para elegir si quiero ordenar por marca, por cilindraje o por precio, pero cuando le doy a cualquiera de estas opciones, el programa no hace ni imprime nada.

Intenté poner la opción de imprimirMotos() dentro de ordenarMotos(), pero no me ordena los nodos, solo los imprime de la misma forma en la que fueron ingresados.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad tu código si esta haciendo algo,un repetitivo bucle(loop) y es debido al primer `while`,en tu método `ordenarMotosa()` el cual siempre sera true debido a que
el `nodoi` nunca pasa a tener un nodo siguiente que sea `null`,lo otro es que el `nodoj` debe pasar a tener su mismo nodo siguiente pero le asignas el `nodoi` siguiente eso tambien te generara un loop

```
Motocicleta nodoi = cabeza;
          if (cabeza.siguiente != null) {
            while (nodoi != null) {
            Motocicleta nodoj = nodoi.siguiente;
              while (nodoj != null) {
                switch (OpcionAtributo) {
                  case 1:
                    if (nodoi.getMarca().compareTo(nodoj.getMarca())> 0) {
                      intercambiar(nodoi, nodoj);
                    }
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    if (nodoi.getCilindraje() > nodoj.getCilindraje()) {
                      intercambiar(nodoi, nodoj);
                    }
                    break;
                  case 3:
                    if (nodoi.getPrecio() > nodoj.getPrecio()) {
                      intercambiar(nodoi, nodoj);
                    }
                    break;
                }
//Solo tendrias que aplicar los siguientes cambios para evitar loop
                    nodoj = nodoj.siguiente;
    
                  }
                  nodoi = nodoi.siguiente;
                }
```